# builder.Prompts.text not working after being hosted remotely

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a simple bot that fetches news articles based on a user prompt. The entire flow works fine locally using emulator but after being deployed to a server the bot fails when it hits a builder.Prompts.text block. Below is my code and you will see a "Asking article count" prompt which is where it stops in flow.

- Bot shows accepted when testing on the BOT Framework page
- Bot is receiving messages via WebChat and Slack
- Bot also shows 0 issues for each channel after interacting

  ```
  var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
  var intents = new builder.IntentDialog();
  bot.dialog('/', intents);

  var HHCC = require('./hhcc.js');



  intents.matches(/^news/i, [
      function(session) {
          console.log("Intent Given!");
          session.beginDialog('/news');
      },
      function(session, results) {
          session.send('Enjoy reading!');
      }
  ]);

  bot.dialog('/news', [
      function(session) {
          console.log("Asking article count");
          builder.Prompts.text(session, 'How many articles would you like to see?');
      },
      function(session, results) {
          session.sendTyping();
          session.conversationData.count = results.response;
          HHCC.getNews(session.conversationData.count, session, function(newsArticles) {
              newsArticles.forEach(function(newsCard) {
                  session.send(newsCard);
              });
              session.conversationData.news = newsArticles;
              console.log(newsArticles);
              session.endDialog();
          });
      }
  ]);


  server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
  ```

Ive checked all logs and can't seem to find any clues as its failing pretty silently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted using builder.Prompts.number() instead of .text()? It only accepts numbers and (I'm guessing you're doing this) you won't have to parse the results.response into a number. Without provided error messages or logs it's difficult to help.

One thing you might have to look out for (if using builder.Prompts.number) is if a user provides a decimal, as the prompt will accept this input, requiring the bot to round to the nearest integer.

Also, if you've saved the results.response into your session object, you will not need to pass in session.conversationData.count as another parameter to HHCC.getNews(). You can instead access it from session in your function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! As of now I am not even getting the prompt to come back to any platform and since we dont have access to the Botframework logs I can't see where the dropoff is occuring. So when I type "news" it triggers the intent and I see both `console.logs` on our servers logs but no response returns to the whatever client I am using.

Comment: Are the `console.logs` for testing purposes? I'm wondering if they are perhaps interfering (though I can't imagine why they would); you said the bot works locally using the emulator but not when deployed and accessed through WebChat and Slack. If you're using the `console.logs` for the developer's benefit then I would add something benign after them such as `session.send` and look for changes. If the same events occur with the `session.sends`, I would look for changes by changing those logs to `session.send`.

Comment: Just tried this and session.send is not returning anything to client either, also replaced the console.logs with session.sends as well. :( not sure what is going on

Comment: Yuck :( I think I'm about out of things to attempt... Not a real "fix" but, have you tried using Azure Bot Service?

Comment: Have not, let me try and stand the app up on Azure, currently using Rackspace.